# Accessing .sqlite db from phpmyadmin? FF cookies

Tags: sqlite, cookies, phpmyadmin

I'm trying to view my firefox cookies db (cookies.sqlite). Since I've never accessed dbs with anything other than phpmyadmin, I'm at a loss as to how to view the content of this sqlite file. There's localhost/sqlitemanager, but I'd rather stick to the phpmyadmin interface that I'm used to.

Any ideas how I can open/view this sqlite db the normal way in phpmyadmin? Is it possible?

Thanks in advance

P.S. I know that browser cookies are very commonly accessed/played with. If you know another tool that's more specific for this goal, please drop me an answer or suggest in the comments.

Answer (score 3):

There are also several web interfaces for sqlite.

[phpSQLiteAdmin](http://phpsqliteadmin.sourceforge.net)

[SQLiteManager](http://www.sqlitemanager.org/index.php?lang=en)

[Simple SQLite Manager](http://sourceforge.net/projects/silsm/)

[SQLite Admin](http://www.phpro.org/sqlite/)

[WizSQLiteAdmin](http://wiz.homelinux.net/php.php)

[ezSqliteAdmin](http://sourceforge.net/projects/ezsqliteadmin)

[SQLiteWebAdmin](http://www.sqlitewebadmin.org)

[knoda](http://www.knoda.org)

I have not yet tried any of them - in fact, I found this SO question while researching sqlite web front-ends for my own use. But I, too, come from a phpMyAdmin background, so the first one I plan to try is phpSQLiteAdmin.

Answer (score 1):

I imagine there are various GUI programs that will hold your hand. However, I'm going to show you what I would do if I was interested in table `moz_cookies` in db `cookies.sqlite`.

```
$ 
$ sqlite3 cookies.sqlite
SQLite version 3.5.9
Enter ".help" for instructions
sqlite> .schema
CREATE TABLE moz_cookies (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, name TEXT, value TEXT, host TEXT, path TEXT,expiry INTEGER, lastAccessed INTEGER, isSecure INTEGER, isHttpOnly INTEGER);
sqlite> select * from moz_cookies limit 1;
1248713741170186|PREF|ID=12d44375be9e7c86:U=d07dae1b87f4537c:LD=en:NR=100:TM=1248713740:LM=1254091506:FV=2:IG=3:S=Jdo_PXt92J5ojL6E|.google.com|/|1317163505|1255144201180851|0|0
sqlite>
```

You may want the sqlite3 CLI program. It is available on Unix and Windows.

```
SQLITE3(1)                                                          SQLITE3(1)

NAME
       sqlite3 - A command line interface for SQLite version 3

SYNOPSIS
       sqlite3 [options] [databasefile] [SQL]

SUMMARY
       sqlite3  is  a  terminal-based front-end to the SQLite library that can
       evaluate queries interactively and display the results in multiple for‐
       mats.  sqlite3 can also be used within shell scripts and other applica‐
       tions to provide batch processing features.

DESCRIPTION
       To start a sqlite3 interactive session, invoke the sqlite3 command  and
       optionally  provide  the name of a database file.  If the database file
       does not exist, it will be created.  If the database file  does  exist,
       it will be opened.
```

It has two categories of operations.

Commands intended directly for the interactive shell begin with `.`. Anything is an SQL query terminated as usual with `;`.

Answer (score 0):

[Adminer](http://www.adminer.org/) is a PHPMyAdmin-like system that has support for MySQL, PostgreSQL, **SQLite**, MS SQL, Oracle, SimpleDB, Elasticsearch, MongoDB, etc.